# Vector tileset not accurate at lower zoom levels

Tags: javascript, mapbox-gl-js, vector-tiles, tippecanoe, mapbox-api-vectortiles

I am creating a web map that will allow users to click on a polygon and have information about the polygon displayed (the polygon also gets highlighted).

I have 4000+ polygons displayed on the map. The issue is when a polygon is clicked, the map is highlighting a different but nearby polygon.

**At higher zoom levels the map is highlighting the correct polygon**. I've tried different ways to create the vector tileset (Tippecanoe and MTS), but I keep running into the same problem.

Also, I have the cursor turn into a pointer when hovered over the tileset but it does not do so for some polygons. Sometimes the cursor points where there isn't any polygon.

Please help...

Comment: You need to include code for a minimal reproducible example.